# Real-time function graph display

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic, procedural-programming, monitoring

I would like to see how the graph of the function `en[B, i, j, k, p]` changes depending on `i`, `j`, `k`, `p` in real time. In my case, the graph is not shown inside the loop at all.

How could it be done?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

en[B_, i_, j_, k_, p_] := B*2*(i + j/k) + Exp[-p*i]

For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
 For[j = 1, j < 4, j++,
  For[k = 1, k < 3, k++,
   For[p = 1, p < 2, p++,
    TE[i_, j_, k_, p_] := Table[{B, en[B, i, j, k, p]}, {B, 0, 6, 1}];
    Pause[0.2];
    ListPlot[
     Table[{TE[i, j, k, p][[l, 1]], TE[i, j, k, p][[l, 2]]}, {l, 1, 
       7}], PlotRange -> All]]]]]
```

Comment: Why not use `Manipulate`? From the documentation for `For` "Unless an explicit Return is used, the value returned by For is Null." Try `Print@ListPlot[...]`.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi, thanks for the comment! When using this construction `Print@ListPlot[...]`, all graphs are displayed on the screen. I would like the graphs to change each other, i.e. the second graph changed the first graph on the screen, after which the third graph replaced the second one, and so on. I would like to have one card on the screen, the content of which changes depending on the changes in the `i`, `j`, `k`, `p`.

Comment: Try to define `plots= {0}` and then `Dynamic[plots][[-1]]` before the loop. When you then run the `For` loop with the `AppendTo` in Rohit's answer, the line with `Dynamic` should update and show you the latest plot. Can you try it? I'm away from my Mathematica machine for a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't be surprised if this is a duplicate, but it's easier for me to write an answer.

Solution using `Dynamic`:

```
Dynamic@plot

en[B_, i_, j_, k_, p_] := B 2 (i + j/k) + Exp[-p i]

plotlst = Table[Pause[0.2];
                plot = ListPlot[Table[en[B, i, j, k, p], {B, 0, 6}], 
                                PlotRange -> All, 
                                DataRange -> {0, 6}, 
                                PlotLabel -> Row[{{"i, j, k, p"}, 
                                                  " = ", 
                                                  {i, j, k, p}}]], 
                {i, 4}, {j, 3}, {k, 2}, {p, 1}];
```

Solution using `Monitor`:

```
en[B_, i_, j_, k_, p_] := B 2 (i + j/k) + Exp[-p i]

Monitor[
        plotlst = Table[Pause[0.2];
                        plot = ListPlot[Table[en[B, i, j, k, p], {B, 0, 6}], 
                                        PlotRange -> All, 
                                        DataRange -> {0, 6}, 
                                        PlotLabel -> Row[{{"i, j, k, p"}, 
                                                          " = ", 
                                                          {i, j, k, p}}]], 
                        {i, 4}, {j, 3}, {k, 2}, {p, 1}];, 
        plot]
```

As to the reason why *the graph is not shown inside the loop at all*, please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124077/1871).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be possible to use this `Dynamic@plot` construct with the loops from my code.

Comment: @MamMam Please, at least avoid `For`…: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/1871

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `For` then

```
en[B_, i_, j_, k_, p_] := B*2*(i + j/k) + Exp[-p*i]

plots = {};
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, 
 For[j = 1, j < 4, j++, 
  For[k = 1, k < 3, k++, 
   For[p = 1, p < 2, p++, 
    TE[i_, j_, k_, p_] := Table[{B, en[B, i, j, k, p]}, {B, 0, 6, 1}];
    AppendTo[plots, 
     ListPlot[
      Table[{TE[i, j, k, p][[l, 1]], TE[i, j, k, p][[l, 2]]}, {l, 1, 7}],
      PlotRange -> 75]]]]]]

ListAnimate[plots, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! In your code, the graphs are displayed on the screen after all the functions have already been calculated. Is it possible to make it so that as soon as the function is calculated, it is immediately displayed on the screen? After that, as soon as the next function is calculated, would it replace the previous one on the screen?

Comment: Why do you need it to be plotted as soon as it is calculated? Isn't the end result the same? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: In real case each graph takes quite a long time, so I would like to watch each graph as it is calculated.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `Monitor`. Example from the documentation `values = {};`
`Monitor[NIntegrate[Sqrt[x (1 - x)], {x, 0, 1}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> (Pause[0.025]; AppendTo[values, x];)], 
 Quiet@ListPlot[values]]`